# HUAWEI can't get user email info in https://oauth-api.cloud.huawei.com/

Tags: huawei-developers

i do authorization in my app with huawei -
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/get-user-info-0000001060261938

i want to get access token, then male request to obtain user info, but can't get
email[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc9Wn.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hruwa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can check:

Image 1 shows the request parameter getNickname set as 1. According to the doc: "When getNickName is set to 1, the nickname is returned." Therefore it is possible for the response only show a displayName only (not an email). The email is usually masked as a display name.
Attempt to can change getNickname = 0 and try again.

If above change is not working, according to the [developer documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/get-user-info-0000001060261938), "...information, such as the...email address, can be obtained only if the app has the permission to obtain the information."

You can check that your app has the permission and has been properly applied to your app and try again.

Share
Edit
Follow

Comment: problem was in the huawei permission
thanks for the reply:) 

but now a have another challenge : i can't get     "displayName": "olga.g**********@***il.com", without  "***", although "access to your profile and nickname" chosen in login process